# Using a cursor and variable to run a seperate query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help with using a cursor and variable to populate a query.  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

What I am trying to do is populate a temp table with inserts,  run through the one column of data to generate a variable that will then populate a query that will check the number of rows in a table.  Here is what I have so far:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#part_tables') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #part_tables

create table #Part_tables 
(table_Name nvarchar(100))

Insert INTO #Part_Tables (table_name)
SELECT [InstancesTable] FROM [BAMPrimaryImport].[dbo].[bam_Metadata_Partitions]
WHERE [ArchivingInProgress]=0 and ArchivedTime IS NULL
      and creationtime < dateadd(DD,-21,getdate())
  GO

Insert INTO #Part_Tables (table_name)
SELECT [RelationshipsTable]  FROM [BAMPrimaryImport].[dbo].[bam_Metadata_Partitions]
WHERE [ArchivingInProgress]=0 and ArchivedTime IS NULL
      and creationtime < dateadd(DD,-21,getdate())
GO


DECLARE @count_query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(100)

SET @Value ='Select Table_Name from #Part_Tables'

SET @count_query ='
    select count (*) from @Value with (NOLOCK)'
WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        EXEC(@count_query + ' option(maxdop 5) ')
    IF @@rowcount < 1 BREAK;
END
```

If this will work, great!  If you have a different / better way to do it, I would appreciate any guidance that someone could offer.

Comment: This has [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) written all over it. Ask about the problem, not about your solution.

Comment: I wanted to at least present what I have been doing to show that I had been thinking and trying different things.  I can change my question to just present the problem and see what solutions are offered.

Comment: It's good to show your attempts, but it seems to me that the question was about it instead of about the actuall problem you want to solve. Forgive me if I've got the wrong impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a much simpler way to get the row counts from those tables. No need for cursors or while loops. And be careful with that NOLOCK hint...it can do a lot more than just dirty reads. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select count(*) from ' + QUOTENAME(InstancesTable) + ' UNION ALL '
FROM [BAMPrimaryImport].[dbo].[bam_Metadata_Partitions]
WHERE [ArchivingInProgress] = 0 
    and ArchivedTime IS NULL
    and creationtime < dateadd(Day, -21, getdate())

set @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)

select @SQL --uncomment exec statement below when satisfied this is correct

--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: I do understand what you mean by dirty reads, but I did not want to lock production tables just trying to get a general count of rows.  This doesn't appear to count the rows in the destination tables.  I was hoping to do this all in one whack.

Comment: Never mind.  Looks like the values that were returned are correct.  I saw 0 counts, but they are empty anyway.  Much appreciated.

Comment: So this does or doesn't do what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: This does.  Much appreciated.  I was trying to overthink it.